# Compiling data from all workbooks in a folder

Tags: database, vba, excel

I have a folder with 150+ timesheets that are formatted the exact same way and that I want compiled in a "master" workbook. Namely, I need 4 cells per timesheet to be replicated in the master:

Cell C4 (date)
Cell B7 (name of employee)
Cell I50 (hours on site)
Cell H50 (hours in office)

The master workbook would have to look like this:

[Master workbook: the goal][1]

Simply said: I need a macro that runs though all excel files in a specific folder and copies information to a "master" workbook.

I'm not an expert at this but I can handle some beginner level macros. I really need this so any help is appreciated! Thanks!

EDIT: I found a macro that copies the second row of each file. That's a starting point but I don't have the skills to edit it...

```
 Sub ConFiles()

    Dim Wbname As String
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim lngCalc As Long
    Dim lngrow As Long

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        lngCalc = .CalculationState
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With


   Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    'change folder path here
    FolderName = "J:\15-0023_Vauquelin\8.0 Phase-construction\FdT fictives"
    Wbname = Dir(FolderName & "\" & "*.xls*")

    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.ClearContents
    Do While Len(Wbname) > 0
        Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderName & "\" & Wbname)
        Set ws = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        'change sheet name here
        Set ws = Wb.Sheets("Heures")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        lngrow = lngrow + 1
        ws.Rows(2).Copy ws1.Cells(lngrow, "A")
        End If
        Wb.Close False
        Wbname = Dir
    Loop

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = lngCalc
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `I can handle some beginner level macros` Have you tried writing something then?

Comment: No, I usually import some that has already been written. I am "familiar" with macros...

Comment: Well, then the solution to your problem seems to be to learn VBA a bit better so you can understand and - more importantly - improve the written code you encounter. If you have a specific question though please feel free to return and ask - but you can't expect us to do all your work just because you don't want to learn for yourself.

Comment: Sooo I fooled around with the code and I came up with what I wanted! I f anyone lands on this page in the future, here it is:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Fetch_Heures2()

Dim Wbname As String
Dim Wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim lngCalc As Long
Dim l

ngrow As Long
    Dim lngcol As Long

'Cell C4 (date) Cell B7 (name of employee) Cell I50 (hours on site) Cell H50 (hours in office)
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    lngCalc = .CalculationState
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With




Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TempData")
    'change folder path here
    FolderName = "J:\15-0023_Vauquelin\8.0 Phase-construction\FdT fictives"
    Wbname = Dir(FolderName & "\" & "*.xls*")

    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.ClearContents
    Do While Len(Wbname) > 0
        Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(FolderName & "\" & Wbname)
        Set ws = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        'change sheet name here
        Set ws = Wb.Sheets("Heures")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then
        lngcol = 0
        lngrow = lngrow + 1
        lngcol = lngcol + 1
        ws.Cells(4, "C").Copy ws1.Cells(lngrow, lngcol)
        lngcol = lngcol + 1
        ws.Cells(7, "B").Copy ws1.Cells(lngrow, lngcol)
        lngcol = lngcol + 1
        ws.Cells(50, "I").Copy ws1.Cells(lngrow, lngcol)
        lngcol = lngcol + 1
        ws.Cells(50, "H").Copy ws1.Cells(lngrow, lngcol)
        End If
        Wb.Close False
        Wbname = Dir
    Loop

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = lngCalc
    End With
End Sub
```